# Identifying parameters accepted by API request

Tags: api, scraping

I'm playing around with the data.gov API and was trying to reconstruct a API request from the websearch.
ex: COVID-19 datasets filtered by Texas
my url looks like

```
https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?q=COVID-19++&sort=views_recent+desc&as_sfid=AAAAAAVj354uPLWh4A-rtCGREQUj1meuoN7meraqiIpM0fYfGGWoEaGfEPqUjArih-22d-oaV26Dhfu_Id9XjdmN1nx2RQRL_KrLPw3K57Fv7P5zT9Z0HR3-ShUHdp8UvZdqXuM%3D&as_fid=8563fb05fbeea54c88ab1649dfdc5c5933f46436&ext_location=Texas&ext_bbox=-106.6501%2C25.8456%2C-93.5074%2C36.4939&ext_prev_extent=-110.390625%2C22.43134015636061%2C-89.82421875%2C37.579412513438385
```

and yields 36 results

But when I use just the *q* and *ext_location* parameters in the following request get a much higher result.

```
https://catalog.data.gov/api/3/action/package_search?q=COVID-19&ext_location=Texas
```

I understand that *ext_bbox* and *ext_prev_extent* are related to the spatial search and adding them to my requests gives me my expected results.

My question is how do I find the parameters that are accepted in package_search API ?
(The [CKAN documentation](https://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-1.7.3/apiv3.html) does not go into details here)

**TLDR**; How does one identify parameters that are accepted in an API request

Answer (score 1):

if you can read code, PHP code, there a client API

- https://github.com/GSA/ckan-php-client/blob/7602dec864c25cfe5f3f96910cdaa8620ea6d57d/src/CKAN/OrganizationList.php

more precisely in:https://github.com/GSA/ckan-php-client/blob/7602dec864c25cfe5f3f96910cdaa8620ea6d57d/src/CKAN/CkanClient.php#L510

You should see here too:

- http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/api/index.html

By experimentation I found these parameters:
https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?tags=cases
&groups=
&res_format=
&ext_prev_extent=
&ext_bbox=
&q=
&organization=
&sort=
&ext_location=
&publisher=
&bureauCode=
&as_sfid=
&as_fid=